# Remove everything from a cell thats within <> in Google Sheets

Tags: regex, google-sheets, substitution, regexp-replace, re2

I know there are a lot of topics about removing characters from Google Sheets cells. I've tried to find a way how to solve my issue with the information on the web / stackoverflow but I can't find it...

I need to create a column with text in multiple rows. The original file still has styling codes `<p> <strong> <i>` etc in it. I need to remove these styling codes. So actually every `<>` code should be removed from the cell. I tried to do this with substitute but than I can only say f.e. remove `<p>` and I'm still having the other styling codes in the sheet.

I think this could be done with **REGEXREPLACE** but I cant get it working. I hope that someone can help me to understand how I can get this working. Thank you!

[image: Overview of things to get rid of]

Comment: `=INDEX(REGEXREPLACE(Z2:Z,"<.*?>",""))` maybe?

Comment: Perfect it works! An addition to it, it also works in combination with an ARRAYFORMULA 

`=ARRAYFORMULA(INDEX(REGEXREPLACE(D2:D,"<.*?>","")))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(D2:D, "<.*?>", ))
```

in some cases that wont be enough so:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(D2:D, "<\/\w+>|<\w+.*?>", ))
```

and in some cases even that wont be enough so:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(D2:D, "</?\S+[^<>]*>", ))
```